# Is there any evidence the tale of the 3 brothers is based on The Wishing-Table, the Gold-Ass, and the Cudgel in the Sack?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any statement or evidence that [The Tale of the 3 Brothers](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Three_Brothers) is based on the fairly tale [The Wishing-Table, the Gold-Ass, and the Cudgel in the Sack ( Tischlein deck dich, Goldesel und Knüppel aus dem Sack)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wishing-Table,_the_Gold-Ass,_and_the_Cudgel_in_the_Sack). Which in my opionion share some elements:

- 3 brothers
- receive magical items
- which 2 of them backfire and only 1 makes the owner happy
- one of the items is an unbeatable weapon (kugel vs elder wand)
- more?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is in a very broad tradition of tales featuring three brothers, two of whom make bad choices and are justly rewarded, and the third of whom makes a good choice and receives his due. The best-known of this class, of course, involves two brothers who build their houses out of flimsy materials, and one who builds his out of brick. There might have been a wolf involved somewhere....

Comment: @Adamant Love the comment, but for me this fairy tale is told when I was younger, so when reading HP I immediatly thought of this story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JK Rowling has said in a [Web chat](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript) that this tale was influenced (to some degree) by Chaucer's "The Pardoner's Tale."

> Jessie: Were the deathly hallows based on any realworld myth or faerie tale
>
> J.K. Rowling: Perhaps ‘the Pardoner’s Tale’, by Chaucer.

She is widely read though and does not deny borrowing from a wide range of mythologies to form her world.

You may also find the Wikipedia article [Harry Potter influences and analogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_influences_and_analogues) interesting, they cite their sources well and break down the admitted degree of influence effectively.